# How should we deal with geochemical anomalies in stream sediment?

Tags: geology, geochemistry, minerals

We know that geochemical anomalies in stream sediment usually distributed along the drainage. Therefore, when we use stream sediment as the sampling medium and found an anomaly, we should trace the anomaly along the stream to find the origin related to the anomalies. But in the procedure of mineral prospectivity mapping (MPM) with support of GIS, we did not perform the procedure of tracing geochemical anomalies along the stream, but directly use the geochemical anomalies as an evidence layer to overlay with other type of evidence, such as geophysical anomalies, fault buffer, etc. My question is why there is no need to do the tracing step in MPM?